Is online nikkah valid?
If a young man and woman, are on a phone call and they put the call on speaker and in the presence of two witnesses that are sitting with the man in the same room, accept each other as husband and wife three times and also decided haq meher to be given to the woman by the man. Is the nikkah valid? This is also recorded on video.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that a qadi  (qazi) is not necessary for nikah. The question is rather about the validity of a nikah made online and without the guardian of the bride.

Firstly, according to the majority of the scholars the guardian of a woman conducts her marriage and she can not marry by herself. Her guardian is her father or other male family member if available.
Secondly, the majority view is that the groom, guardian of the bride and witnesses must all be present in the same place for the contract to be valid. The groom or guardian can however appoint agents over the phone who can meet to form the contract.
Ref: https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/473371/marriage-was-done-through-the-phone and https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/89838/marriage-and-divorce-via-the-internet
